# Python - Passing list of fields as column to SQL query

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to pass a list of columns into a SQL query in Python. This just returns back the list but not the actual columns as shown:

```
cols = ["col_a","col_b","col_c"]


query = f"""select '{cols}' from table"""


Current Output : f"""select '["col_a","col_b","col_c"]' from table"""

Expected output: f"""select col_a, col_b, col_c from table"""
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to do a `join` of the list:

```
query = f"""select {", ".join(cols)} from table"""
```